# Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.VerbatimMessageException was unhandled

Tags: vb.net, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I have code that updates the TFS Global List, so when a new customer is added to our customer tracking software, it updates the Client Name list.

The code is able to get the GlobalList and update the xml. However, when I call `store.ImportGlobalLists(globalList.InnerXml)` I get an exception. The `store` variable is a `WorkItemStore` The only relevant information I could find on this exception is [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dff44124-6168-46c4-8ecb-3caf05fea26c/error-tf223006-you-cannot-modify-the-definition-of-a-work-item-tracking-object-with-your-version-of?forum=tfsadmin), which doesn't give much additional information. The exception gives additional information:

> You cannot modify the definition of a work item tracking object with
>   your version of command-line tools as they are not compatible with the
>   Web services for Team Foundation Server. Contact your system
>   administrator to determine how to upgrade your installation of Team
>   Explorer to a version compatible with Team Foundation Server.

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.25431.03 Update 3
- .NET Version 4 (not using NuGets for TFS Communication)
- TFS Version 2015 (14.102.25423.0)

The full exception is below:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.VerbatimMessageException was unhandled
  ErrorId=0
  HResult=-2146232832
  IsRemoteException=True
  LogException=False
  Message=TF223006: You cannot modify the definition of a work item tracking object with your version of command-line tools as they are not compatible with the Web services for Team Foundation Server. Contact your system administrator to determine how to upgrade your installation of Team Explorer to a version compatible with Team Foundation Server.
  Source=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Provision.ProvisionClass.Submit(ActionType action, MetadataProvider mdp, Int32 projectId, WITImporter importer)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Provision.ProvisionClass.ImportGlobalListsInternal(XmlElement listsElement)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Provision.ProvisionClass.ImportGlobalLists(String lists)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.ImportGlobalLists(String lists)
       ...
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       Actor=/tfs/DefaultCollection/WorkItemTracking/v4.0/ClientService.asmx
       HResult=-2146233087
       Lang=""
       Message=TF223006: You cannot modify the definition of a work item tracking object with your version of command-line tools as they are not compatible with the Web services for Team Foundation Server. Contact your system administrator to determine how to upgrade your installation of Team Explorer to a version compatible with Team Foundation Server.
       Node=/tfs/DefaultCollection/WorkItemTracking/v4.0/ClientService.asmx
       Role=""
       Source=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.RetryHandler.HandleSoapException(SoapException se)
            at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.WorkItemServer.Update(String requestId, XmlElement package, XmlElement& result, MetadataTableHaveEntry[] metadataHave, String& dbStamp, IMetadataRowSets& metadata)
            at CProdStudioBackendChannel.Update(CProdStudioBackendChannel* , Boolean fBatchSave, UInt16* bstrXMLUpdateData, UInt16** pbstrXMLUpdateData, WorkItemServer clientService)
       InnerException:
```

As a side note, I did try updating my TFS Power Tools to 2015, but that was already installed. I do have VS 2010 and VS 2017 installed, but it sounds like it is okay to have multiple versions of Power Tools side-by-side.

Comment: Locally with `witadmin` do you success to import the global list?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk - Yes, I was able to export using witadmin. I made a change to the results and tried using witadmin importgloballist and received the same error I did above.

Comment: Other users can import the globallist from their machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client to version 14.102.0. To do this, I needed to update the solution to .NET 4.5, and update a few other NuGets to get the code to not show errors after building.

I still run into exceptions in the process, but this specific question was resolved this way.